# SSAS facts sharing the same dimension

Tags: multidimensional-array, ssas, dimensions, cubes

I'm building a cube with 2 fact tables that share some dimensions. 
In the example below, I have Fact_Employee, Fact_Manager, Dim_Date, Dim_Country, Dim_Employee and Dim_Manager, with the respective links.

[image: DataSource View]

In SSAS I've created one Dim_Country. In the Cube "Dimension Usage" I am creating 2 dimensions (Man_Country and Emp_Country) and linking to the respective measure groups.

My Fact_Employee has the key for the Dim_Manager, so I can relate them.

My problem here is, when in the pivot table I drag the Man_Country, Emp_Country, Emp_Amount and Man_Amount, this doesn't work  because I'm getting the list of all Manager Countries not related to the Manager Number and then the Employee Countries are correctly linked to the Employee Number, but are duplicate. 
The below image shows the result Pivot table and what I am trying to get.

[image]

What do I need to change in the data source view or cube dimension usage to have the correct results.

The users should be able to filter the pivot by, for example, Manager Country to see all the employee Countries and Numbers and the amounts (for Managers and Employees).

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,
PC

Comment: Why not create 1 dimension that contains all Managers/Employees with a field that says whether they're a manager or not and a field that shows what employees are linked to what manager? Then, have 1 Fact Table  with 1 amount field that you can roll up on Manager/Employee?

Answer (score 0):

If you have country dimension then **you should use this dimension for both measure groups**, just remember to configure dimension usage for this dimension vs both measure groups.

There are special cases where you would want to separate those dimensions, f.eks:if you want them to act separately - let say you have a fact table with parcels and you need to have both DimFromCountry and DimToCountry. In this case you would want to use role playing dimension - it is same dimension then, but connected differently.